# How to apply css rule over some classes and avoid others

Tags: html, css, sass, uibutton, hover

There are some buttons in the application, some of them look like real buttons while others have other icons and they are used for sorting lists.

I want to add hover to the buttons but to avoid it for the "sorting" buttons.

This is the code:

```css
.ui.button {
  background: #262445;
  color: #ffffff;
  &:hover {
    background: #3c3669;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  &:active,
  &:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #1a1635;
  }
}
```

the difference is only on the background.

All the buttons in my code contain `ui.button` class in inspect mode. The "sorting" buttons also contain `ui.button.sort-buttons-inactive` or `ui.button.sort-buttons-active`.

I've tried like this

```css
.ui.button {
  background: #262445;
  color: #ffffff;
  &:hover:not(sort-buttons-inactive):not(sort-buttons-active) {
    background: #3c3669;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  &:active,
  &:focus:not(sort-buttons-inactive):not(sort-buttons-active) {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #1a1635;
  }
}
```

so when the element doesn't contain `sort-buttons-inactive` or `sort-buttons-active`  it should not do any changes when hover.

However, it doesn't work. The normal buttons work fine but it also changes the "sorting" buttons , it changes its color to white (#ffffff) which should not happen.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your full-stop on your class selector.

```
:not(sort-buttons-inactive):not(sort-buttons-active)
```

Make it

```
:not(.sort-buttons-inactive):not(.sort-buttons-active)
```